# Passing handlebars variable to javascript function or JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to pass handlebars variable to javascript function or JQuery function ?

I am trying to something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var first = {{name}}
  var last  = {{last}}

  $("#name").text(first + ' ' + last); 
})
```

Comment: Can you show your handlebars code?

Comment: To get first and last name you need to get it from the place where you use handlebars. You can't use `{{ }}` in javascript.

Comment: I want to popup login box if the user has not logged in when he click on any link on the page, currently i am placing the status in  hidden div in the page, I want to circumvent the trouble of passing the variable in the page and then read it. I was hoping to read the {{status}} directly in javascript and popup login box. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `name` and `last` are string.
Then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var first = "{{name}}";
  var last  = "{{last}}";

  $("#name").text(first + ' ' + last); 
})
```

But be sure to escape the " and newlines in your `name` and `last` vars.

Comment: I must doing something wrong ...

I am getting {{name}} {{last}} instead of John Doe

Not sure why variables are not getting evaluated.